# Get all tags between two elements (XPath)

Tags: html, xpath

I have html like this:

```
<!-- some content -->
<div class="content">
  <h5>First title</h5>
  <p>some text 1</p>
  <p>some text 2</p>
  <h5>Second title</h5>
  <p>some text 3</p>
  <p>some text 4</p>
</div>
```

I need to get all tags between h5 tags and if second h5 tag does not exists, get all tags after first h5 and to end of the div.content

I can get all tags between two h5 via xpath:

```
//h5[starts-with(., 'First title')]/following-sibling::*[following-sibling::h5]
```

And I can to get all tags between first h5 and end of the div.content via xpath

```
//h5[starts-with(., 'First title')]/following-sibling::*
```

But I have no idea how combine these two rules :(

Comment: Please share the code you've tried, problems you've encountered, research you've done, stack overflow is not a free coding service.